# Deep linking in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn deep linking in angular.

As I click on a link which is created with ng-repeat like on the exp below:

```
<ul ng-controller="ShowOrderController">
   <li ng-repeat="car in cars"><a href="#ShowOrder/cars.indexOf(car)">
   {{car.Brand}}</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

It doesn't display relevant detail of the clicked link

I understand that I am not linking that properly on my controller:

```
sampleApp.controller('ShowOrderController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

  $http.get('data.json').
    success(function(data){
      $scope.cars = data;
      $scope.car_id = $routeParams.carId;
    });

});
```

I just can't figure out or find any source that explains plainly how to create deep linking..

Exp: http://plnkr.co/edit/7D0UegRrtKPxrZ8zfxEL?p=preview

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I think you need is interpolation like `href="'ShowOrder/{{cars.indexOf(car)}}"`

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't fix it. Plus, car.id targets the right view(like: #showorder/3)..

Comment: The use `href="'ShowOrder/{{car.id}}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. working [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IW8G4Pj3jMCTzBdZpm0Y?p=preview)

You may change the filter as like below

```
<div ng-controller="ShowOrderController" ng-repeat="car in cars | filter: { id: car_id } | limitTo:1">
```

Comment: That solves it indeed.. Why would it show BMW and KIA if I click on BMW? but thnx anyway!

Comment: yes, actually, it is not working as expected..means KIA id has "10"..angular matches that item also when search "1". Checking on it..let you know once found.

Comment: Updated the demo with additional filter "limitT:1" and it is working fine now with your json data. but still need to involve more to find better solution that angular way exact matching syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't defined the filter(i.e 'query1'). Take a look at the following code.

```js
sampleApp.controller('ShowOrderController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

  $http.get('data.json').
    success(function(data){
      $scope.cars = data;
     
    });
  $scope.car_id = $routeParams.carId;
  id=$scope.car_id;
}).filter('query1',function(){
    return function(array){
      if(array){
        for(var i in array){
        if(array[i].id===Number(id)){
          return [array[i]];
        }
      }
      }
      
    }
});
```

And the working plunker is here [plunckr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7D0UegRrtKPxrZ8zfxEL?p=preview) .